# Wedderburn's second structure theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In the proof of Wedderburn's second structure theorem 
on page 7 of the link below:

http://pages.uoregon.edu/brundan/math647fall99/ch5.pdf

I don't understand why 1 is necessarily contained in finitely many of the Ui's.

Which they use to prove that there are only finitely many such simple modules.

can someone please explain?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read closely: It says $1$ is contained in a *finite sum* of the $U_i$'s. That is because, by definition of the direct sum, *every element* of $\bigoplus_{i\in I} U_i$ is already contained in a finite sum, or more precisely, all but finitely many of its coordinates $u_i$ are $=0$.

Say $J$ is the finite subset of $I$ such that $u_i = 0$ for $i \in I \setminus J$, where  $1 = (u_i)_{i \in I}$. Then because $r = r\cdot 1 = (r_i u_i)_{i\in I}$ for any $r = (r_i)_{i \in I}$ in the ring, all $r_i$ for $i\in I\setminus J$ are $0$. So we can actually restrict the sum to $\bigoplus_{i\in J} U_i$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the fact that every element of $\bigoplus_{i\in I} U_i$ is a *finite* sum of elements of the $U_i$.  Since $1 \in \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i$, then there exist indices $i_1, \ldots, i_m \in I$ and $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ with $u_k \in U_{i_k}$ such that $1 = u_1 + \cdots + u_m$.  Thus $1 \in U_{i_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus U_{i_m}$.

Comment: I see, a follow up question would be:  this theorem asserts that the isomorphism is module, not necessarily ring?

Comment: Yes, I take the notation ${_R R}$ to mean $R$ considered as a left $R$-module.  I think the second paragraph on p. 6 of the linked notes supports this interpretation.